# fixed div hiding behind other div when scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, sticky

I set this div as two small flags to choose the language of the page. They are fixed (sticky) on top right of the screen. Problem is when I scroll, because they hide behind other elements such as images or background colors. How to make them not hide anymore?
I tried setting parent class as 'navbar' and somehow it works, but the elements wrap up when screen shrinks.

```css
#flags {
  position: fixed;   
}
```

```html
<div style=" float: right; width: 100px; margin-top: 60px;">
  <div id="flags">
    <span>
      <a href="default.html">
        <img  id="uk" src="images/uk.png">
    </span></a>
    <span><a href="default_ita.html">
      <img  id="uk" src="images/italy.png">
    </span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to close a tag then span `</a></span>`

Comment: Try setting 'z-index' higher than other element for the element that you want to be at the top like 'z-index:99'

Comment: that's what i was looking for! Thanks :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go with a solution using `z-index`

Provide the highest `z-index` to the element which you want to view all the time, condition the element should have position fixed

```css
#flags {
  position: fixed;
  z-index:9999   
}
```

```html
<div style=" float: right; width: 100px; margin-top: 60px;">
  <div id="flags">
    <span>
      <a href="default.html">
        <img  id="uk" src="images/uk.png">
      </a>
    </span>
    <span>
      <a href="default_ita.html">
        <img  id="uk" src="images/italy.png">
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Please have a look in the closing tags as well `span` tag got closed before `anchor` tag

Hope this will help you.

Comment: why put a value as `9999`, you know you can get away with a far lower value in many cases, for example `z-index: 2;`

Comment: @לבנימלכה Have a look into this https://jsfiddle.net/a0vkw8s4/1/ You will understand whether z-index works with position fixed or not.